# Retrieve MIN and MAX date in one query

Tags: mysql

I have in a mysql database a table "travel_data" with three relevant columns:

```
+--------------------------+
| from  | to   | date      |
+--------------------------+
|City1 | City2 | 2015-12-12|
|City3 | City4 | 2016-12-12|
|City1 | City2 | 2015-06-06|
|City3 | City4 | 2017-01-01|
+--------------------------+
```

(plus a few other colums  that I don't need at the moment).

I'm looking for a query that allows me to get, in one query if possible, the first and last date for each itinerary per row, i.e. something like:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|from  | to    | firstTravelDate | LastTravelDate|
+------------------------------------------------+
|City1 | City2 | 2015-06-06      | 2015-12-12    |
|City3 | City4 | 2016-12-12      | 2017-01-01    |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

I've search for "mysql select maximum minimum in one query" but solutions from there, inasfar as they worked at all, returned mix/max per table; I need the min/max per possible combination of from/to. This has me baffled to an extent where I haven't even a start for a working query. This needs to run only on MySql, so a standards-compliant solution is not necessary.

(Improvements on the title are welcome, I don't feel the title fully covers the actual question).

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query.  Are you familiar with `group by`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not nearly enough it seems. I can group by my itineraries and I managed to get either min or max date, but not both in the same row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Gordon indicated in the comments, this is a simple aggregation query. You will want to do the following

```
SELECT `from`, to, 
       MIN(date) AS firstTravelDate, 
       MAX(date) AS LastTravelDate 
FROM travel_data 
GROUP BY `from`, to;
```

You may need back ticks on the variables "FROM" and "TO" since those are reserved keywords in MySQL.

Also, in the interest of "teaching you to fish" as it were, I would recommend taking a look at https://sqlschool.modeanalytics.com/. There are a lot of SQL resources out there, and Mode's focuses on PostgreSQL not MySQL... but it's also very good and very fun to read.

Comment: Thank your for the help. I used to know quite a bit of SQL, but apparently it doesn't stay with you if you do not practise. I'll definitely do the recap :-) Will upvote and accept as soon as I've had opportunity to test.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if there are any issues :)

Comment: Thank you again ! I was thrown off by the fact that phpMyAdmin on my server gave erratic results no matter what query, once I started testing on the command line things worked beautifully.

Answer (score 3):

Try;

```
select
   `from`, `to`, min(date) firstTravelDate, max(date) LastTravelDate
from travel_data
group by `from`, `to`
```

**Demo**  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6088/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can make variable for your 'from' and 'to'
then run:

```
select min(date),max(date)
from yourtable
where travel_data.from=x
and travel_data.to=y
```

Comment: I actually don't think that will work. You would have to iterate over all possible values of from and to, which is going to be extremely inefficient, especially compared to simply using SQL as intended and performing an aggregation grouped by from, and to.